# NuGet Package restore failed for visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I am using Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10 machine. I have  one application which was working fine in Visual Studio 2012. But if I try to run in Visual Studio 2015, it is showing error as below. Circular Progress is a DLL in my application for animation.

> "NuGet Package restore failed for project BITservice: Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'CircularProgressBar'.."

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
jerin

Comment: Have you set up your NuGet sources in Visual Studio 2015 to include the repository that contains your CircularProgresdBar package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NuGet Package restore failed for project myProjectWeb: Unable to find version '3.0.1' of package 'AppForSharePoint16WebToolkit'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303669/nuget-package-restore-failed-for-project-myprojectweb-unable-to-find-version-3)